# Georeferencing photographs using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, georeferencing, photos

I have 563 photographs that have been taken as part of a site survey. The only location information that I have is a single GPS location (lat,long) at which the photograph was taken. I am looking for a Python Script (ArcPy) that will use the GPS location of each Photograph (Point Feature Class) and then based on a given width and height georeference each photograph. It's important to read the raster properties to determine if the image is portrait or landscape.

Can you provide sample code in ArcPy?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding determining if the image is landscape or portrait, that information is all embedded within the EXIF headers of the image and it's pretty easy to get it out using a library such as [`exifread`](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py):

```py
>>> import exifread
>>> f = open("DSC_8185.JPG", "rb")
>>> tags = exifread.process_file(f) # tags is a dict of info
>>> orient = tags["Image Orientation"] # this photo is portrait
>>> orient
(0x0112) Short=Rotated 90 CW @ 42
>>> f = open("DSC_8187.JPG", "rb")
>>> tags = exifread.process_file(f)
>>> orient = tags["Image Orientation"] # this photo is landscape
>>> orient
(0x0112) Short=Horizontal (normal) @ 42
```

Then you can just use the `in` operator to determine the orientation:

```py
if "Rotated" in str(tags["Image Orientation"]):
    # it's rotated, do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this methodology to determine if it is landscape or portrait:

```
top = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("RASTERNAME","TOP")
bottom = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("RASTERNAME","BOTTOM")
right = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("RASTERNAME","RIGHT")
left = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("RASTERNAME","LEFT")

width = abs(right - left)
height = abs(top - bottom)
if width > height:
    orientation = "landscape"
else:
    orientation = "portrait"
```

Once you have this - you can add 1/2 the height and 1/2 the width to get the upper right corner and subtract 1/2 the height and 1/2 the width to get the lower left corner.